# multithreading application in c

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a multithreaded application but got some doubts. Can anybody please clarify one this?

My main goal is to

1. Create five threads to execute the work concurrently.

The program for this is:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pthread_create(tid[i], NULL, func, NULL)
}
```

Then generally we call for the `pthread_join()`:

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
{
    pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
}
```

So here my question is that in this call of `pthread_join()`, if thread 2 finishes first then thread 2 will wait for thread 1 to finish as we have put in a sequential loop for the `pthread_join()` function.

Comment: What do you mean by `if thread 2 finishes first then thread 2 will wait for thread 1 to finish as we have put in a sequential loop for the pthread_join function`?

Comment: My question is all the thread will do their work independently if am not wrong on func. If somehow thread 2 finish it works before thread 1 finishes

Answer (score 4):

```
for(j=0; j< 5 ; j++) 
{
   pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
}
```

Means wait for thread with `tid[0]` to finish. If it is already finished, return immediately.
Then wait for thread with `tid[1]` to finish. If it is already finished, return immediately and so on.

In short, this for loop will make sure, current (possibly main) thread would not exit before children thread.

Answer (score 3):

The for-loop is executed sequentially,

```
for(j=0; j< 5 ; j++) 
{
   pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
}
```

so regardless of which thread finishes first, the for-loop will wait for thread 0 first, and then thread 1 etc.   If thread 2 actually completes first then the result of that thread will simply just hang around until the join is executed -- this is similar to the way the `wait` call works if you were to wait for specific process ids.

Comment: If I wanted to make it non blocking then I do have to remove pthread_join as I understood from you. So my basic am is to create 5 threads in a continuous loop and execute some command independently. for that I wrote the below program which is stopping after sometimes.Can you please have a look on this.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS 10
void *thread_function(void *);
int main()
{
        pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];
        int i, j;
        while(1)
        {
                for(i=0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
                {
                        pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL );
                }
                 /*
                for(j=0; j< NTHREADS; j++) {
                        pthread_join(thread_id[j], NULL); 
                } */
        }

        return 0;
}
void *thread_function(void *dummyPtr)
{printf("iniside thread \n");}

Comment: If you let the main thread exit then the other threads will be killed, possibly (probably!) before their work is done, and that is not a good idea.

Comment: If you want to syncronize the exit of the threads you will have to implement some sort of syncronization method -- the possibilities are many and too long for this format, but includes mutex semaphores and many other methods.  Alternatively if you are not interested in the join-result, why not just mark the thread non-joinable and it can just exit when it wants to without any syncronization?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is not doing something magical. So it calls

```
  pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[3], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[4], NULL);
```

in the above order.

If you want to join threads in some other order, you need to use explicitly some synchronizations *inside* your `func`. You may want to use condition variables and mutexes. Read a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use  **pthread_join()** function in a loop, your system will wait until first thread  is returned, then the second one and so on. If the second thread is finished, it will wait for the first one and then it will take care of the second one.